# How to set router path

Tags: tomcat, routes, openshift

What folder need to set in routes path?

i use: 
Openshift v3
Tomcat

now i get on start page :

Application is not available

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

Comment: I would check your application logs and look for errors or post your log file here.

Comment: If you use ``oc rsh``, or the web terminal for the pod in the web console to get an interactive terminal in the pod, can you make requests by running ``curl http://localhost:8080`` and ``curl http://$HOSTNAME:8080``. This will check whether your application is handling requests at all.

Comment: logs have no error and write build successfull; curl http://localhost:8080 and curl http://$HOSTNAME:8080 answers is empty